# ResourceManager override GetResourceFileName

Tags: c#, reflection, methods, overriding, private

I want to override a method in the System.Resources.ResourceManager class in mscorlib v4.

I want to override the method GetResourceFileName like this;

```
    protected override string GetResourceFileName(CultureInfo culture) {
        string resourceFileName = base.GetResourceFileName(culture);
        return resourceFileName.Replace(".resources", ".resx");
    }
```

The problem is, to instanciate a ResourceManager class I must use the static method CreateFileBasedResourceManager, which returns a new instance of the ResourceManager. (because I need the file based resourcemanager)

How can I override this method? I also tried to call the private constructor CreateFileBasedResourceManager calls to create the object, but i'm getting this exception (can't invoke private constructor with reflection?);

```
    [SecurityException: Request failed.]
  System.RuntimeMethodHandle.PerformSecurityCheck(Object obj, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal method, RuntimeType parent, UInt32 invocationFlags) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks) +323
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +38
   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters) +35
   System.Xml.Xsl.XsltOld.FuncExtension.Invoke(XsltContext xsltContext, Object[] args, XPathNavigator docContext) +164
   MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.FunctionQuery.Evaluate(XPathNodeIterator nodeIterator) +430
```

Answer (score 2):

Create your own resource provider and reference it in your app.config or web.config. An example can be found [here](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbresourceprovider/)

Comment: Thanks for the info, afterall using the Activator class to instanciate the object with the private constructor worked... the securityexception was from something else.